# Unicode.Net failed to install library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, package-managers

I simply want to install  Unicode.NET library, what do i do wrong?
(I'm using VS Community 2017, V:15.3.4)
[image]

Comment: `Assert` does not come from that library, but from a unit testing library...

Comment: So what just Unicode.NET library gives you? (all i need is the thing that turns special characters to their simple English form)

Comment: Wrong question. What are you trying to do? Why do you think you need that call to `Assert`?

Comment: You want to use a library and you don't even know why? Walk away from the IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the NUnit-test framework as well. The red underlined code is a hint that the compiler cannot resolve the assert-function used in your code, which is part of the NUnit-framework. 
Just look for [enter link description here](http://nunit.org/)

So get the package, add the reference to your project and don't forget the using directive:

```
using NUnit.Framework;
```

Comment: You definitely don't _need_ to install that, unless you want to do unit testing. It's not a dependency for using this library.

Answer (score 2):

This library is an emoji and text-processing library for .NET. They are using Assert from xUnit library. Take a look at their [source code from github.](https://github.com/thecoderok/Unidecode.NET/blob/master/test/UnidecoderTest.cs) inside the tests folder.

[Read more here](https://github.com/neosmart/unicode.net)